# Finding a complex orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

**Question:** Find an orthonormal basis $u_1$,$u_2$,$u_3$ for $\mathbb{C}^3$ such that $u_1$ is a multiple of $(1,w,w^2)$, where $w=e^{2i\pi/3}$.

I know that I must apply Gram-Schmidt, but I am unsure how to even get $u_1$. I don't know how to work out norms when there is an exponential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get $u_1$, divide $(1,w,w^2)$ by its norm. The norm is
$$\sqrt{1+|w|^2+|w^2|^2}=\sqrt{1+1+1}=\sqrt{3}.$$
This is because $w=e^{i2\pi/3}$ has absolute value $1$. The norm of $re^{i\theta}$ is $r$.

Answer (score 1):

If the inner product in question is Hermitian, then you can easily build such a basis. Observe that

$$1+w+w^2=0$$

and

$$w^3=1$$

Using this, it is easy to prove that the basis

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ w \\ w^2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ w^2 \\ w\end{pmatrix}
$$

is orthogonal. Then you can simply normalize them (divide by $\sqrt{3}$, as suggested by KittyL) to get an orthonormal one.

In fact, these vectors form the columns of the 3-dimensional unitary [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).